# Find the area of the region bounded by $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 2a^2(x^2 -y^2)$, $x^2 + y^2=a^2, (x^2 + y^2\geq a^2)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the area of the region bounded by $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 2a^2(x^2 -y^2)$, $x^2 + y^2=a^2, (x^2 + y^2\geq a^2)$. What should I do? I substituted first expression with the second one and got 4 points : $P1(\frac{\sqrt3}2a,\frac12a)$,$P2(\frac{-\sqrt3}2a,\frac12a)$,$P3(-\frac{\sqrt3}2a,-\frac12a)$,$P4(\frac{\sqrt3}2a,-\frac12a)$. Is it a correct approach?

Comment: Using symetry, you should probably calculate the area in the first quadrant and multiply by 4. Polar coordinates should help you to find the integral, with angle $\theta$ varying from $0$ to the angle from the $x$-axis to the line $OP_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious approach is to convert to polar coordinates.

So you want the region bounded by $a\leq r\leq a\sqrt{2\cos 2\theta}$ ($2\cos 2\theta\geq 1$).  Symmetry therefore gives
$$
A=4\int_0^{\pi/6}\int_a^{a\sqrt{2\cos 2\theta}}r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
which you can easily evaluate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how did you get first inequality?

Comment: You stated you want $x^2+y^2\geq a^2$, i.e., $r\geq a$, in the question.  The other curve $(x^2+y^2)^2=2a^2(x^2-y^2)$ is in polars $r^4=2r^2a^2\cos 2\theta$.  So we get the upper bound $r\leq\sqrt{2\cos 2\theta}$.